# SQS Consumer keeps on polling after being stopped

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a Node app that is observing a SIGTERM signal once it is sent by the cloud orcherstator.
As a first step, I shut the SQS consumer, than I wait until all tasks run to completion, but even though I shut the consumer it is still keeps on processing messages after close operation.

```
    if (consumer != null) { // sanity check
      logger.log("Stopping SQS consumer...");
      try {
        consumer.stop();
        logger.log("SQS consumer stopped.");
      } catch (error: any) {
        logger.warn(`Error stopping SQS consumer during shutdown, this ain't good. error=${error}`);
      }
    }
```

```
{"name":"Index","hostname":"blah","pid":1,"level":"info","msg":"SQS consumer stopped.","time":"2023-03-21T22:58:13.418Z","v":0,"timestamp":"1679439493418"}

{"name":"Index","hostname":"blah","pid":1,"level":"info","msg":"Message received:  ...", "time":"2023-03-21T22:58:14.872Z","v":0,"timestamp":"1679439494872"}
```

The time diff is 1,5 seconds between those messages.

How can this behavior be explained?

```
"sqs-consumer": "5.6.0"
```

https://github.com/bbc/sqs-consumer/

Scratching my head over this.

Comment: just to clarify you are using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sqs/index.html or (it seems to me that you are maybe using this) https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqs-consumer?

Comment: https://github.com/bbc/sqs-consumer/

Comment: @IvanVasiljevic yes, that is the latter one